# Vertical gradient causing scanlines

Tags: html, css

Trying to place a top-to-bottom gradient as my background, but for some reason vertical gradients are causing the background to create scanlines.

[Image Of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKSZG.png)

Here's my stylesheet:

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: a better solution is to use `html {min-height: 100%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `min-height` to your body.

```css
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: min-width is not needed

Comment: true, I'll edit the answer